# UdpClient can't receive from DatagramSocket

Tags: c#, datagram, udpclient

I am making an application. server side works on desktop and client side works on Windows 8 (Metro App- .Net for Windows Store)

here is my server code:

```
var udpServer = new UdpClient(7800);
udpServer.BeginRecieve(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpRecieve), null);
. . .
private void OnUdpRecieve(IAsyncResult result)
{
    byte[] data = udpServer.EndReceive(result, ref peerEndPoint);
    udpServer.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpRecieve), null);
}
```

and here is my client code on Win RT:

```
var udpClient = new DatagramSocket();
await udpClient.ConnectAsync(new HostName("localhost"), 7800);
var udpWriter = new DataWriter(udpClient.OutputStream);
udpWriter.WriteBytes(new byte[] {0, 3, 5});
await udpWriter.StoreAsync();
```

but on the server side I am not getting anything. I thought maybe I am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well I read a question on MSDN forums. It was not my answer but there were a point there that "loclhost" differs from "127.0.0.1".

When you use "localhost" you force datagram to use IPv4 and when you use "127.0.0.1" you force the datagram socket to use IPv6.

That's the point ;)

Comment: Perhaps you have the IPv4 and IPv6 backwards? "127.0.0.1" is an IPv4 address.  "::1" is the equivalent IPv6 address.  "localhost" could be either, at the system's whim.